# PowerBI - Dynamic Headers in Table/Matrix Visual

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded

Is there a way to dynamically change Table/Matrix visual headers in PowerBI, either using DAX or something else.

Sample data:

[image]

So, when it turns to next month the header should be like:

[image]

I would highly appreciate your help and support.

Thank you,

Comment: Use matrix with only last 3 months in the table. Either limit the number of months when loading data, or apply top N filter on the data to filter out all rows except last 3 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add Relative date filtering as "in the last 3 months

[image]

Just to show "in the last 6 moths"
[image]

Comment: thank you, this is just perfect.
now, I got another issue. I have multiple columns to be added in matrix visual. If I add    another column it is showing as header.

Comment: @RuchitaP  I think the asked question is answered. Could you please first mark this as solved and we can try to help you further.